# Are sprouts a good replacement for animal/whey protein?

Tags: protein, protein-shakes

I find the taste of Whey protein unnatural and was wondering if I could supplement workouts with sprouts, apparently they contain 35% protein.

http://www.care2.com/greenliving/10-reasons-to-eat-sprouts.html?page=1

Would 200g a day of sprouts allow a 160 pound trainer enough protein to maintain lean muscle mass?

Answer (score 1):

I can't find what I would consider a reliable reference for the 35% figure.

As far as I can make out, (mung) Bean Sprouts are about 3% protein. So 200 grams would give you about 6 grams. Alfalfa sprouts have slightly more perhaps 4% protein.

A Guideline Daily Amount or protein for a man would be 55grams and 45 grams for a woman.

So, I'd have to say no, 200g of sprouts would not be enough protein on its own.

http://nutritiondata.self.com/facts/custom/602335/2

http://nutritiondata.self.com/facts/vegetables-and-vegetable-products/2302/2

http://www.gdalabel.org.uk/gda/gda_values.aspx

Comment: I want to add, the RDA of 55/45 grams is if you don't move, _at all_. General consensus for strength training individuals (if that's what you are) is a minimum of 1g/lb. I was the one downvoting btw, for that exact reason.

Comment: It depends on age/sex/weight, but those GDA amounts are for somebody reasonably active maintaining their weight / lean mass. (But not body building). EG a 25 year old man 160lbs 5ft9 tall working out 3 times a week would require about 2350 calories a day, and those protein amounts a for somebody requiring 2400 calories a day.

Comment: I do not approve of the GDA and I outright reject it for anyone doint sports. GDA states you'd need 55g for 2500kcal, that's ~11% of the total calories consumed. I don't think that will be enough for someone that's actually (weight) training. Also GDA recommends 120g sugar per day. That doesn't sound like a healthy nutrition to me.

Comment: That 120 grams of sugar comes pretty much from sugars in fruit and veg. 1 apple can have 23 grams of sugar. But yes, newer research has shown that less sugar is better.

Comment: GDA is just taking the easy way by stating that a certain amount of 'sugar' is okay. We all know that your average person will not read 'apple', but 'chocolate bar'. In that aspect (and not only that one) the FDF is just lazy, maybe even intentionally misleading, and do not live up to their responsibility.

Comment: "We all know that your average person will not read 'apple', but 'chocolate bar'." Yes, I'd agree with that. But the average person considers a 30 minute run as training for a marathon. Regarding protein requirements the question is about maintaining lean muscle mass in a 160lb person and to maintain muscle actually requires a lot less protein than to manufacture new muscle. Again, you are right that the GDA figure is on the low side for somebody who is well muscled, rather than carrying a lot of fat.

Answer (score 1):

I too was in a similar dilemma when I gave up protein shakes. I tried eating way too much protein from a specific source.

- A protein shake is a [supplement](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/supplement), a thing that makes up for a deficiency. The thing is that in today's world, especially in first world countries, protein is everywhere and its easily obtainable through eating whole nutrition dense foods.
- Eating large quantities of bean sprouts will lead to certain mineral and vitamin deficiencies. In general, **"too much of anything is bad for you, even if its a healthy food"**.
- Focus on a eating a well balanced diet for an active individual with different foods. Eat *enough/moderate* proportions, *not too much*.
- If you are still struggling to meet your protein requirements, try out [full fat whole milk or raw milk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kJWTbjeEvVY) if its **legally available** in your country/state and you are **not allergic to milk**. Milk is a great way to make good healthy muscle gains that stay with you. But remember consume it in moderation and that goes for everything else you eat.

I hope this helps. Lastly, **Keep on learning** about eating a well balanced nutritious diet. There is still so much stuff we don't know about the food we eat and how it affects our body

Answer (score 0):

A very good source of proteins is uncooked nuts, though they are acidic.

Also super good: green leaves, one of the best things you can eat and to help digestions: make a green smoothie out of it.

Sprouts are certainly good, I can't confirm the quality, as it depends on a lot of other factors, such as: how much do you workout, what do you eat for the rest.